# How to get right position of Element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wish to get the right position of an element. I have tried `attr('right')` and I have read the API document regarding `.position().right` which is non existent *(I believe)*.

http://jsfiddle.net/xavi3r/vcuq7/

Is an example I wish to alert the right value for.

Comment: i believe it was a revenge vote from the previous answer which i down voted as it didn't answer the question.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You want to find the value of the CSS `right` property?

```
$('#foo').css('right');
```

In plain Javascript:

```
document.getElementById('foo').style.right;
```

But, if you want to find the *calculated* distance from the right edge of an element to the right edge of another one, then you'll have to do that yourself, combining `.position().left` and `.offsetWidth`

Comment: thanks i just required the right value which is calculated prior.  Thanks

Comment: I find it frustrating that JavaScript (and jQuery) don't do the work of calculating the right-position on your behalf.  It seems a very obvious thing to want to do, and it would be nice if the framework allowed you to abstract away from having to calculate it for yourself.

Comment: @nickf I don't see how `.position().left` and `.offsetWidth` can give you the equivalent of an hypothetical `.position().right`. To compute the value of a `.position().right` *relative to the offset parent*, you'd have to know the `.offsetWidth` of the current element **and** of that offset parent, the latter being missing part. Am I missing something?

Comment: @avernet: I guess it'd be `(parent.left + parent.width) - (el.left + el.width)`

Comment: @nickf Right, except the parent might not be the closest offset parent. Luckily for us, jQuery can give us the closest ancestor element that is positioned with `.offsetParent()`. With this, we can easily get the "right position" of `el` with `$('body').width() - (el.offsetParent.offset().left + el.offsetParent().width())`.

Comment: If you want to retrieve the position relevant to the viewport, you might try `window.innerWidth - document.getElementById('foo').getBoundingClientRect().right`

Comment: For absolute positioning over the document, I used: `($(document).width() - $el.offset().left - $el.outerWidth())`

Answer (score 13):

It looks to me that this works:

```
jQuery('#elem').offset().left + jQuery('#elem').width()
```

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/adamovic/fcyL5sg0/

Comment: Thanks for the idea @Mladen Adamovic

Answer (score 5):

```
$(document).width() - ($('#elem').offset().left + $('#elem').width());
```

should get you the space on the right side of the element which you can then set as the value for the 'right' property of the element's position;

Answer (score 5):

The CSS value is only valid if it's set via style or $.css().

But if you need to get the right position of an object, you should do it using javascript / jquery.

Although there are some valid solutions, it's important to note that $.fn.width() doesn't take padding and borders in account. So it's better to use **outerWidth()**.

Example:

```
$(document).width() - ($('#elem').offset().left + $('#elem').outerWidth());
```

You can even create a $.fn function to get the value:

```
$.fn.right = function() {
  return $(document).width() - (this.offset().left + this.outerWidth());
}
```

And then use it:

```
$('#elem').right();
```

Comment: The OP asked about `position` (relative to offsetParent) vs you answered using `offset` (relative to the viewport)

Answer (score 2):

you can try `.css`

`.css("right");`

Comment: in most cases this returns 'auto' if the right property is not explicitly set in the css and what I think the OP wants is the absolute value of the right of the element in pixels?

Answer (score 2):

As noted by @avernet in comments, the equivalent of an hypothetical .position().right would be expression like this:

```
$('#foo').offsetParent().width() - ($('#foo').position().left + $('#foo').width());
```

Comment: As mentioned by @Jorgeblom's answer, this would be better if you used `outerWidth`

Answer (score 2):

for pure js you can use

```
document.querySelector('.your-class').getBoundingClientRect().left
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.